# Is The Mac Pro Making A Comeback?

Tags: discussion

This might be more appropriate to place this on a Blog (I'm not sure if Ask Different has one If so I'd like to put it there.)

A few months back I read that the Mac Pro was being discontinued (at least in Europe anyway). Was that in fact just a ["red herring"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Herring) & is it actually being re-introduced ?

If so, what can Apple fans look forward to in this new beast ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do have a blog, so you could write up what you want to post as an answer here and we can see about getting you an account if we've got something large enough to post.

The blog is linked in the row of links at the bottom of every Ask Different page (the meta links to stack exchange's blog and not Ask Different's blog, so don't get surprised by that):

- http://apple.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1

As you can see, we would love some more content to post if you care to step up with an article.

Comment: Ok thanks very much

Comment: The blog has been rather dead lately, but an actual article from a site participant might be exactly what it needs to jumpstart!

Comment: @simon it appears Apple has provided ample ammunition to anyone wishing to shoot down the premise that the Mac Pro is dead. We'll certainly have room for a few posts on the blog once the hardware is released.

Comment: @bmike I'm not sure if it was going to be discontinued in America, it certainly was (according to reports a couple of months ago) here in Europe. Its looks absolutely amazing from what i've seen, (although overkill for most people i'm sure), if I win the lottery then yes, otherwise I'll get myself a Mac Mini :). Still longing for the day when Apple announce a 15"  Macbook Air

Comment: @simon - Yes the current Mac Pro was withdrawn since it didn't meet new fan design rules in the EU. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90641/have-apple-ceased-selling-mac-pros-in-the-uk/90644#90644 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80587/what-are-the-regulatory-requirements-that-will-halt-the-sale-of-the-mac-pro-in-e

Comment: @bmike Ah I see, but now thats it been totally redesigned, its back.